How to alias sections of a branch name in git
I have branch names organized into sections like:

AAA/BBB/branch1
AAA/BBB/branch2
AAA/CCC/branch1
AAA/CCC/branch2

I want to alias sections of these branch names.
So for example, I want to be able to type A/B/branch1 instead of AAA/BBB/branch1.
I need to be able to alias the individual sections (A = AAA, B = BBB), and not the whole branch name, because when I create another branch such as AAA/BBB/new_branch, I need to be able to instantly access it with A/B/new_branch.
I tried:

using git symbolic-ref.
adding an alias in the .bashrc or .zshrc file.

Neither of these seem to work for aliasing only a section of a branch name.

It sounds like you might need a branch autocomplete?

@evolutionxbox The problem with my autocomplete is that it's really slow. I'm using Windows with git bash, zsh, and oh-my-zsh.

I was hoping you could use symlinks, but I just tried it and it didn't work

One solution could be making a bash script that took your whole command and just replace "A/B/Your_branch" by "AAA/BBB/Your_branch" then just alias the call of the script with something that you can easily call.

So if I understand correctly, instead of using the command "checkout AAA/BBB/my_branch", I first call the script: "script checkout AAA/BBB/my_branch" ?

@JeroenR: No, you just call script checkout A/B/my_branch

Oh yes, that's what I meant. Interesting idea, but I was hoping for something that wouldn't require the script call.
